# How do I change from a 302 temporary to a 301 permanent redirect code?

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-301

I currently have a 302 temporary code on one of my websites. Although I could identify this code, i could not locate it. Where can I find it and how can I change it from 302 temporary to a 301 permanent redirect code?

Comment: How did you setup the redirect?

Comment: @Blender through the OVH manager, my internet service provider but they do not allow to change the specific redirect (there is only one option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your site is on an apache server, you can in principle set the redirects by using the .htaccess file. A guide below plus a useful coding page from Webado:

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/index.php?a=1

http://groups.google.com/group/only-validation/web/fix-canonical-issues-www-vs-non-www-and-more-on-apache-server